# Cant get angular 2 to scale with app subdectory folders

Tags: angular

I am using the default boiler plate from anguaryjs tutorial site.  I want to create  component into a directory of app e.g.

```
app/git/git.component.ts
```

Yet

I cant find the below.

```
import {Component} from '@angular2/core';
```

So..how do I import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your folder structure. You're mixing the beta-style `angular2/<module>` imports with the RC-style `@angular/<module>`.

Replace

```
import {Component} from '@angular2/core';
```

by

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
```